# Chart js - Polar Scatter Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, scatter-plot, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to plot a simple Polar Scatter Plot like this.

[image]

How do I do it using Chart.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart.js is limited to creating polar charts that look like [this](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/polar.html). If you want a higher degree of control to look exactly like the image you've posted, I would look into something like [d3](https://d3js.org/). If you're new to data visualization, I'd start with chart.js. They make it straightforward to initialize a polar chart.

```
new Chart(ctx, {
    data: data,
    type: 'polarArea',
    options: options
});
```

Here's a fiddle of what the code would look like. http://jsfiddle.net/eHmSr/110/

Comment: Which library do you recommend for scientific data visualization? Could provide an example of how to do it in d3.js?

Comment: I just came across this example using potly.js. It seems the closest to what you want.

https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/ZGPRBY

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure Chart.js doesn't provide Polar Scatter Plot?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Chart.js is known for its great charts + simplicity. It doesn't have a lot of customization.